# NVMe drive for video intensive work

Tags: ssd, video-editing

For an intensive video processing workflow (lot of sequential reading and seeking), I selected the 2TB Seagate FireCuda 510 SSD M2 and the 2TB Samsung 970 Evo Plus; they have few differences:

- FireCuda has better endurance: 2.6TB written, 1.8Mh MTBF vs 1.2TB written, 1.5Mh MTBF (970 Evo Plus)
- FireCuda has better price: 293EUR vs 366EUR (970 Evo Plus, 25% more expensive)
- 970 Evo Plus has slightly better read/write speeds: (3.5GBps, 3.3GBps, 620kiops, 560kiops) vs (3.45GBps, 3.2GBps, 485kiops, 600kiops)

The other features are not significantly different. What do you recommend for my usage?
I already have a 970 Evo Plus 1TB for the system and for a part of the scratch work; both SSD will be on the Z390's PCIe channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will be lightning fast. After investigation, the 970 is only a bit faster on sequential transfer such as big files, and a bit slower on games and program folders; i.e. for video seeking it will be faster. FireCuda accumulates all the advantages (speed by small margins, twice lifetime/reliability (like 970 Pro), 25% lower price).

[1] https://www.pcmag.com/review/366078/samsung-ssd-970-evo-plus

[2] https://www.pcmag.com/review/368665/seagate-firecuda-510